# Can a JSP tag file access its calling JSP's PageContext?

Tags: java, jsp, el, jsp-tags

If I do:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("foo", "bar"); %>
<custom:myTag/>
```

it seems like I should be able to do:

```
<%= pageContext.getAttribute("foo") %>
```

inside of myTag.tag ... but of course I can't because the tag file doesn't have access to the pageContext (instead it has access to a jspContext ... which doesn't have the same attributes as the calling page's pageContext).

Now, you can access the pageContext via ELScript:

```
${pageContext}
```

but that doesn't help because ELScript has no way of passing arguments, so you can't do:

```
${pageContext.getAttribute("foo")}
```

However, the fact that ELscript can accesss the page context, and the fact that the tag can access all sorts of variables like jspContext, that there must be some way for a tag to access (in a scriptlet/Java logic way, not just in ELScript) an attribute from the calling JSP's pageContext.

Is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As to EL, the `${pageContext.getAttribute("foo")}` works in EL 2.2 only. Before that the right syntax is `${pageContext.foo}` or just `${foo}`. See also our [EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

However, the `${pageContext}` isn't shared between the parent JSP file and the JSP tag. Each has its own instance.

You could *either* set it as request attribute instead:

```xml
<% request.setAttribute("foo", "bar") %>
<custom:myTag />
```

with in the tag

```xml
<%= request.getAttribute("foo") %>
```

or, with EL

```
${requestScope.foo}
```

or

```
${foo}
```

*Or*, better, you could pass it as a fullworthy tag attribute

```xml
<custom:myTag foo="bar" />
```

with in the tag

```xml
<%@attribute name="foo" required="true" %>
${pageContext.foo}
```

or just

```xml
<%@attribute name="foo" required="true" %>
${foo}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I've already got the variables i want in the pageContext, and enough (legacy) code that references them there that I don't want to have to change them to request attributes.  So I *can* just put duplicate copies in to the request too, but I was hoping there was some other way to do it.  Oh, and these variables are going to get passed A LOT in A LOT of tags if I make them attributes, so I was really hoping for a "behind the scenes" solution.  If there is no way possible to access the JSP's pageContext from the tag though ... guess I'm out of luck :-(

Comment: You can just access the actual page context with (PageContext)getJspContext(). See my answer below.

Comment: @Jason: question wasn't about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in WebLogic 10 at least, the implicit "application" object *is* available in tag files, and is instanceof ServletContext. Maybe use this, when it's really the ServletContext that one is after, and not necessarily the higher-level pageContext.